# Windows Phone 8.1 Has No Sample Images?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am testing PhotoChooserTask in my 8.1 app and I do not see any available sample images that come with the emulator? Is there a way to get sample images?

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

        //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        myImage.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code as well?

Comment: @Jedidja - what kind of code would you need to see here?

Comment: I can it is just PhotoChooserTask_Completed event. It is just troubling because how can we test 8.1 with basic choosers? Is there something I have skipped over in the new documentation for 8.1?

Comment: To note, in the 8.0 emulator you used to have to go to load the photos hub app first then your app would be able to use the sample images within the Sample album, otherwise they would not be detected. I tried this in 8.1 with no luck.

Comment: My 8.1 emulator didn't come with any images, but I'm not sure if that's normal (?)

Comment: You can use the camera button to take a "picture" and then you should have at least one photo in your album...

Comment: I need a sample photo for testing purposes with image manipulation and also for screenshots. The picture from the emulator is just the colored lines unfortunately.

Comment: I think the answer to your posted question is that there aren't any sample images included in the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to download from the Internet. I found a great workaround for this.. In the new WP8.1 emulator you have the option to emulate a SD card. Its great. I have created a blog post and a YouTube video. Have a look. Hope it helps.

http://wpdevkvk.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/adding-your-own-photos-to-windows-phone-8-1-emulator/

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator there aren't any images available. Actually there are some images for selecting as the background for the start screen, but it is only available for start+theme app in settings page. You can't access them. But you have a workaround for that. Before you test your app you can open the camera app and take some photos. (Obviously it will take save some images of random squares but it will have to do) Then next time you run the app your PhotoChooserTask has some photos to select from.

Comment: As a workaround I was considering posting my images online and then going to the web browser and saving the images to the emulator, and then gathering from there. Do we have access to save downloaded images from the internet?

Comment: I have found a workaround and posted a new answer, have a look. If it is satisfying and acceptable please upvote and mark it as correct :)